# Update OpenGL to 3.3 from 3.0 on Intel HD Graphics 3000 used Macbook air running Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: opengl

When I typed the following :

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.6.0-devel
```

I found from 
https://support.apple.com/en-ap/HT202823
Intel HD Graphics 3000 (with Sandy Bridge based CPU) supports up to OpenGL 3.3.  I found driver update does not help.  Ubuntu 14.04 is the version I am using which was directly installed meaning not upgraded from lower version of Ubuntu.

Did anybody ever successfully update to OpenGL 3.3 from 3.0?

@dobey:

```
 $ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.6.0-devel
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.6.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
```

This is version info including core profile.  The version core profile shows what I exactly want to have for just OpenGL version and shading language version.

Comment: is it really worth going from 3.1 to 3.0, might be a minor change

Comment: @edward torvalds: OpenGL 3.1 fully removed all of the features which were deprecated in version 3.0, with the exception of wide lines. From this version onwards, it's not possible to access new features using a full context, or to access deprecated features using a forward-compatible context. from wikipedia. I am a first time learner of OpenGL as my materials use 3.1 above versions thinking to update.  Also warning like "You may NOT use the OpenGL “fixed function” pipeline that was removed from OpenGL version 3.1 onwards."

Comment: If you are using 14.04, where did you get _Mesa 10.6.0-devel_ from? The latest released version is 10.5.5, and 14.04 only came with Mesa 10.1.3. With the lts-utopic Xorg packages, you can get 10.3.2. What does glxinfo show for the `OpenGL core profile version string:` in its output?

Comment: @dobey: about the Mesa 10.6.0-devel version.  I got through command : sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev.  Output you asked I answered on my question.